# How to make UINavigationBar taller in portrait mode on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, orientation, uinavigationbar

By default, the UINavigationBar should be tall in portrait orientation and short in landscape orientation. Most of the time, my app behaves like this, but sometimes when changing from landscape back to portrait, the navigation bar does not resize properly. Is there a command to forcibly redraw the navigation bar to the correct height?

This is a screenshot of the mishap. The navigation bar remains short after rotating from landscape to portrait. There is a perpetual white space below the bar, equaling the remainder of the height that it should be.

[image]

My UIViewController has this relevant orientation code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: have you tried overriding `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` and manually setting the height? (I don't have time to test this out, so I just posted as a comment instead of an answer.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It ain't look pretty, but I just I solved it by hardcoding:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.height = 44.0;
```

Where setHeight is a category method for UIViews which, as the name implies, changes the frame's height.